# How to show a table from fields without database

Tags: c#, report

Here is the scenario:

I am using C# windows form, I have textbox and combobox, what I want to happen is whenever I click the button "submit".. a new form/table will open with the details of what was inside those textbox and comboboxes.

I don't need to use database, this thing I am doing is just to show the "report".

Comment: So where do the details come from?

Comment: Not sure if I understood your question. But you can get the details from any .net collection (from a file, from a web service, from a windows service, some cached information in your application) not only from a database.

Comment: Cancel this scenario, i made a new one, pls look below.

Answer (score 1):

You should keep a reference to the value of your Textbox and Combobox and pass it to your form. You have not posted your code, so i am just going to make you a quick example. You would have to define MyCustomForm yourself, make it accept two strings in the constructor, and inherit from Form.

```
string textValue = textBox.Text;
string comboboxValue = combobox.Text;

MyCustomForm form = new MyCustomForm(textValue, comboboxValue);
form.Show();
```

Comment: ok thanks for the input. I planned to cancel that scenario. Here is the new one,, I have a DatagridView on the same form, so when i click the Submit Button, I want the text in Textboxes and Comboboxes to appear in DataGridView. How?

Comment: I think you should read into how you access the data you are after, on the controls you use. And then, how to pass that data around your application logic.

Comment: Problem Solved. Different solution though. Thanks Everyone!!